# Examining interactions when one group is normally distributed and the other is not

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, interaction, nonparametric, skewness

I'm running regressions on some data so I checked to see if the data was normally distributed. I need to create interaction terms using gender so I split the variables by gender and examined them. Some of the variables are only skewed for one gender and not the other. How should this be handled?

Comment: What is it you're checking for normality, exactly, and why?

Comment: I'm checking the variables I'm including in the regression for normality because regression analyses assumes normality.

Comment: What do you think it assumes to be normal?

Comment: Regression analyses assumes the residuals of the regression line are normally distributed... But I'm sure you already know that. If I'm doing it wrong, and you have a solution please let me know.

Comment: I first have to run the regressing with the interaction terms. Then I'll have to run the analysis separately by gender.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're saying in your last comment. Why do you "have" to do those things? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

[Actually the usual assumption is that the *errors* are i.i.d. normal. The residuals are simply our best estimate of those -- not that this is the main issue.]

What concerns me is that in your question you said that you had checked if the *data* were normal, implying you had instead examined either the DV, the IV or both. You then confirmed it in your first comment (when you referred to "the variables"). Please understand that it's important that you clearly provide details of exactly what you did examine (I keep asking, but you're being very shy about it).

Given your most recent comment about the assumption relating to the residuals, your vague mention of "the data" and "the variables" is no longer enough. Describe your variables and explain *exactly* what you did to assess normality, in detail. What are your variables, precisely which variables did you look at when looking at normality, and how did you assess it? What exactly did they show? Can we see?

How large is your sample size? How many variables are there in your biggest model?

The normality assumption matters only in the case of performing inference (hypothesis tests, confidence intervals, prediction intervals), and in large samples it may really only be of concern in the third case. (Other assumptions are much more important.)

However it's perfectly possible to perform inference without making the assumption of normality, but I'd really like to be clearer on what's going on. I'd rather not mislead you by assuming I understand what you're doing.

There are several possible ways you might avoid assuming normality.

Comment: To Glen_b's point, most models and assumptions related to "normally distributed" errors are actually quite robust to violations of these assumptions.